# Multi User record update Windows application using SQL Server & C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multi-user

I am developing a windows application, where multiple users can uses the same database.

My problem is when insert a new record to database table, I need to display the new `customerID` in the customer registration form. For that I get the last customer id and increment by one and display the customer ID of the new customer. In a multi-user environment, if two people are trying to add a new customer at a same time, then there will be problem displaying the new customer id. And when two users accessing and updating the same record at a same time.

What to do?

Comment: does your `customerid` is an autoincrement filed ?

Comment: The **best** solution is to have that `customerID` as an identity column in SQL Server and let the database handle the values. Once those two users have entered their data and saved the customer records, they'll both get a valid, unique `customerID` for their new customer

Comment: IMO. you should not update your database with  `customerID` `txtCustomer.text` instead of that while updating your table update the customer id feld like `UPDATE tbl SET customerID = customerID + 1`

Comment: No, it is Varchar type Example: ACC1001

Comment: Hi @marc_s than for the reply.. the thing is my customer need to see the customer ID... If i set identity i cannot show the customer id and before number i cannot add characters (Example: ACC1001)

Comment: why so ??? if `ACC` is unique for all `customerID` then you can simply add it to textcontrol field by appending acc with customerid filed from table if customerId is integer field and for example 1001 then append ACC to 1001 ie. `ACC1001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get the Last Customer Id and auto increment it by one, it's not safe for the reason you mentioned.

After the insert statement of the new record just select the inserted id and display this to the customer registration form with this line of code:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Or check this select statement which does the equivalent:

```
SELECT @RecordId= MAX([RecordId])
  FROM [dbo].[CustomerTbl]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could output the inserted values into a table variable and then return that value

e.g.

```
DECLARE @output TABLE
(Col1           VARCHAR(10));

INSERT targetTable
(Col1)
    OUTPUT inserted.Col1
    INTO @output
VALUES ('ACC1001')

SELECT Col1 FROM @output;
```